# Start service with ansible role and defaults

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to set up a role in ansible to install some servers with needed applications. One of the apps is docker.

Docker-ce is installed successfully. Now I'm trying to tell the system to startup docker.service and enable it by reboot.

When I'm creating a list over "with_items" it works fine, when I'm trying to use a list out of my defaults/main.yml file ansible tells me that it can't find the service docker. Now I'm wondering, maybe just some spelling problem?

This one works fine

```
  - name: Start and enable needed services
    systemd:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: started
      enabled: yes
      daemon_reload: yes
    with_items:
      - docker
```

This one doesn't work

```
  - name: Start and enable needed services
    systemd:
      name: "{{ clientonline }}"
      state: started
      enabled: yes
      daemon_reload: yes
-------
# in defaults/main.yml
  clientonline:
    - docker
```

Ansible can't find the docker service when I'm using my list from defaults/main.yml

```
 [WARNING]: The value ['docker'] (type list) in a string field was converted to u"['docker']" (type string). If this does not look like what you expect, quote the entire value to ensure it does not change.
```

Also this example doesn't work:

```
  - name: Start and enable needed services
    systemd:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: started
      enabled: yes
      daemon_reload: yes
    with_items:
     - clientonline
```

That brings this error:

```
failed: [fgi_appdeploy_server] (item=clientonline) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "clientonline", "msg": "Could not find the requested service clientonline: host"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that will work:

```
- name: Start and enable needed services
    systemd:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: started
      enabled: yes
      daemon_reload: yes
   with_item:
     - "{{ clientonline }}"
```

since `clientonline` is a list you need to loop through it

Comment: I want to use a list like the one I've posted:

```ansible
clientonline:
    - docker
```

to extend the list later on when there are more services to start and enable like httpd or jenkins or whataver. Later on the list would look like this f.e.:

```ansible
clientonline:
    - docker
    - httpd
    - jenkins
    - fancyservice
```

Comment: I'm getting more and more confused. When I've a list of packages that I want to install I also don't need to do it on that way you've posted..... ???

Comment: you called your variable `name: "{{ clientonline }}"` without loop there for you need to specifiy the index or use ` with_items: -clientonline`

Comment: When I'm installing packages with:
```ansible
  - name: Install needed packages
    yum:
      name: '{{ clientpackages }}'
      state: latest
```
it also works without the with_items option.... strange module...

Comment: Your answer doesn't work, ansible throws this error:

```ansible
failed: [fgi_appdeploy_server] (item=clientonline) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "clientonline", "msg": "Could not find the requested service clientonline: host"}
```

Comment: I forgot the curly braces :)

Answer (score 0):

OK; this now works fine for systemd:

```
  - name: Start and enable needed services
    systemd:
      name: '{{ item }}'
      state: started
      enabled: yes
      daemon_reload: yes
    with_items:
     - '{{ clientonline }}'
```

But same style for yum module will bring this warning on bash, nice to know

```
  - name: Install needed packages
    yum:
      name: '{{ item }}'
      state: latest
    with_items:
      - '{{ clientpackages }}'
```

```sh
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Invoking "yum" only once while using a loop via squash_actions is deprecated. Instead of using a loop to supply multiple items and specifying `name: "{{ item }}"`, please use `name: ['{{ serverpackages }}']` and remove the loop. This feature will 
be removed in version 2.11. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
```

Nice to know - thanks to all!